# iOS Triangular Image view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

so I'm making a game and pretty much when the player (which is a triangular shaped rocket) hits an object flying at you (a rock) the game ends. I have everything working well but my problem is the rocket is a triangle yet the image view its in is a rectangle. So if the edge of the image view touches the rock the game will end even though the actual rocket didn't touch the object. So basically how can I make the rock image view not recognize the parts of the rocket image view which are empty? Basically a triangular shaped image view.

Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need more info or want to see the code I have for them to collide.

Answer (score 0):

You analytically present the triangle with 3 points and a rock with a center and radius then find and implement an algorithm checking a hit test between those 2 shapes. Or draw the two shapes onto some graphics context using an appropriate blending and check for overlapping pixels (for instance draw one as red and another as green and look if a pixel that is both red and green exists) you could actually do that with 2 image views having those colors and .5f alpha added on the 3rd invisible view but you would need to get the image from the view and then iterate through all the pixels. In any of the cases do this check only after the corresponding view frames overlap.

Comment: Im sorry but i don't understand

Comment: What part do you not understand? Surely you must understand you need to create a custom collision detector to detect collisions between the custom objects.

Comment: I have never used this type of code/approach before.